# SARIMAX equation

Tags: time-series, arima

I have used SARIMAX to predict energy consumption with Temperature and humidity as external variables.
My model is SARIMAX (1,0,0)(0,1,1)7.

I am having difficulty numerically calculating the predictions using the SARIMAX equation.
I have included sample coefficients and values.

As an example, I want to mathematically reach the value of 1/14/2020 (i.e. 113)
[image]

I have come across the following in a paper but am not able to reach the values I have with the equation, especially the value of the error term at the end of the equation.

[image]

Highly appreciate any help